# Diff 2 long strings and write result in 3rd file

Tags: linux, bash, file, awk

I am working on my initial bash scripts and got stuck at a place where need help from the forum.

How to implement below in shell script? (Any suggestions/pointers are appreciated!!!)

Requirement:

Compare 2 files matchings KEY containing long string and persist in 3rd file only long strings which differ in other attributes (say value of USER is different). Also skip some attributes comparison.

Input FILE1-

```
AAUTOX=Y;ACCT=;ACTION=C;APRICE=99.975;AQTY=5541;USER=Sam,bpl;CONFIRM=Y;KEY=29976DYE4;DEPT=MYNA-CLCD -- same
AAUTOX=Y;ACCT=;ACTION=C;APRICE=05.975;AQTY=3451;USER=Todd,chr;CONFIRM=N;KEY=29976DYE5;DEPT=MYNA-CLCD -- diff (USER=Todd,chr) write in result file
```

Input FILE2-

```
AAUTOX=Y;ACCT=;ACTION=C;APRICE=99.975;AQTY=5541;USER=Sam,bpl;CONFIRM=Y;KEY=29976DYE4;DEPT=MYNA-CLCD -- same
AAUTOX=Y;ACCT=;ACTION=C;APRICE=05.975;AQTY=3451;USER=Alan,ncr;CONFIRM=N;KEY=29976DYE5;DEPT=MYNA-CLCD -- diff (USER=Alan,ncr) write in result file
AAUTOX=Y;ACCT=;ACTION=C;APRICE=17.000;AQTY=6453;USER=Todd,chr;CONFIRM=N;KEY=29976DYE6;DEPT=MYNA-CLCD -- no match (KEY) found write in result file
```

Output FILE3:

```
FILE1:AAUTOX=Y;ACCT=;ACTION=C;APRICE=05.975;AQTY=3451;USER=Todd,chr;CONFIRM=N;KEY=29976DYE5;DEPT=MYNA-CLCD 
FILE2:AAUTOX=Y;ACCT=;ACTION=C;APRICE=05.975;AQTY=3451;USER=Alan,ncr;CONFIRM=N;KEY=29976DYE5;DEPT=MYNA-CLCD


FILE1:

FILE2: AAUTOX=Y;ACCT=;ACTION=C;APRICE=17.000;AQTY=6453;USER=Todd,chr;CONFIRM=N;KEY=29976DYE5;DEPT=MYNA-CLCD
```

and so on for each differed line....

Approach in my mind (It's first cut and cud improve later):

- Read FILE1 line by line (awk or read??)
  For each Line

  - a) read FILE2 for matching unique "KEY" (which command to use here??? Could awk read file based on key??? grep KEY from FILE2 but how to break line into fields for comparison??)
  - b) Now compare each field of FILE1.LINE1 with FILE2.LINE and if different write in 3rd result file (awk breaks line into fields $1, $2 so could compare
    though not sure how to do if use "read" command???)

Comment: expected sample output can help us understand better

Comment: added sample output. Thanks

Comment: Is the order of the result file lines important (can they come out in another order than they appear in the input files)? Is specifying which of the input files the line comes from (i.e. the inserted 'FILE#:' line prefix) important? Is indicating a no match in a file (i.e. the line with just 'FILE1:' in your example) important?

Comment: @DanCornilescu: yes order should be same as input. Yes prefixing filename is required as well. No match is not important but good to have.

Comment: @EdMorton: compare ALL atributes except CONFIRM=.Both input file1, file2 are sorted on KEY attribute. Output File3 has white space infront of input file1 as matching record (KEY) is NOT even present in input file1. It's only present in file2.

Answer (score 1):

This uses GNU awk 4.* for sorted `in` (see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal), with other awks you can pipe to sort or otherwise determine the key order:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[;=]" }
{
    delete name2val
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) { name2val[$i] = $(i+1) }
    key = name2val["KEY"]
    keys[key]
    recs[key,FILENAME] = $0
    for (name in name2val) { vals[key,FILENAME,name] = name2val[name] }
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
    file1 = ARGV[1]
    file2 = ARGV[2]
    for (key in keys) {
        state = "SAME"
        if ( (key,file1) in recs ) {
            if ( (key,file2) in recs ) {
                for (name in name2val) {
                    if (name != "CONFIRM") {
                        if (vals[key,file1,name] != vals[key,file2,name]) {
                            state = "DIFF"
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else { state = "FILE1_ONLY" }
        } else { state = "FILE2_ONLY" }

        if (state != "SAME") {
            print file1":", recs[key,file1]
            print file2":", recs[key,file2]
            print ""
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
$ gawk -f tst.awk FILE1 FILE2
FILE1: AAUTOX=Y;ACCT=;ACTION=C;APRICE=05.975;AQTY=3451;USER=Todd,chr;CONFIRM=N;KEY=29976DYE5;DEPT=MYNA-CLCD -- diff (USER=Todd,c
hr) write in result file
FILE2: AAUTOX=Y;ACCT=;ACTION=C;APRICE=05.975;AQTY=3451;USER=Alan,ncr;CONFIRM=N;KEY=29976DYE5;DEPT=MYNA-CLCD -- diff (USER=Alan,ncr) write in result file

FILE1: 
FILE2: AAUTOX=Y;ACCT=;ACTION=C;APRICE=17.000;AQTY=6453;USER=Todd,chr;CONFIRM=N;KEY=29976DYE6;DEPT=MYNA-CLCD -- no match (KEY) found write in result file
```

Comment: Thanks @Ed for posting the answer. Could you please explain it as well? What statement is doing what? It's a long awk script.

Comment: Sorry but most of this is basic stuff (populating arrays and then looping through the array contents) and IMHO very easy to follow so idk where to start. Is there any particular part of it you're having trouble following?